# How to bifurcate `currencyId` and `currencyCode` from the rest of the items in the `control` array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to bifurcate `currencyId` and `currencyCode` from the rest of the items in the `control` array.
Right now it is giving output like :

```
[{
  channels: {ANDROID: 0,EMAIL: 0,INBOX: 0,IOS: 0,SMS: 0,TELEGRAM: 0,currencyCode: "CFA",currencyId: 11},
  currency: {currencyCode: "CFA",currencyId: 11} 
}]
```

But I want output like :

```
[{
  channels: {ANDROID: 0,EMAIL: 0,INBOX: 0,IOS: 0,SMS: 0,TELEGRAM: 0},
  currency: {currencyCode: "CFA",currencyId: 11} 
}]
```

This is my code so far:

```
let chargesData = [
          {
            "SMS": 0,
            "IOS": 0,
            "ANDROID": 0,
            "EMAIL": 0,
            "currencyId": 11,
            "currencyCode": "CFA",
            "TELEGRAM": 0,
            "INBOX": 0
          },
          {
            "SMS": 10,
            "IOS": 10,
            "ANDROID": 10,
            "EMAIL": 10,
            "currencyId": 12,
            "currencyCode": "IND",
            "TELEGRAM": 10,
            "INBOX": 10
          }
        ]


    let control = [];
    let currency;
    for(let charges of chargesData) {
      let chargesChannels = Object.keys(charges)
      
      let currencyCode = chargesChannels.indexOf("currencyCode");
      let currencyId = chargesChannels.indexOf("currencyId");
      chargesChannels.splice(currencyCode, 1);
      chargesChannels.splice(currencyId, 1);
      
      currency = { currencyCode: charges.currencyCode, currencyId: charges.currencyId };
      control.push({
        channels: charges,
        currency: currency
      })
    }
    console.log(control);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over array and then over object properties using `in` operator and then separate out the object as needed.

```js
let chargesData = [
    {
    "SMS": 0,
    "IOS": 0,
    "ANDROID": 0,
    "EMAIL": 0,
    "currencyId": 11,
    "currencyCode": "CFA",
    "TELEGRAM": 0,
    "INBOX": 0
    },
    {
    "SMS": 10,
    "IOS": 10,
    "ANDROID": 10,
    "EMAIL": 10,
    "currencyId": 12,
    "currencyCode": "IND",
    "TELEGRAM": 10,
    "INBOX": 10
    }
];

const controls = [];
chargesData.forEach(charges=>{
    const control={
        channels:{},
        currency:{}
    }
    for (const key in charges) {
        if(["currencyCode","currencyId"].includes(key)){
            control.currency[key]=charges[key];
        }else{
            control.channels[key]=charges[key];
        }
    }
    controls.push(control);
});
console.log(controls);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let chargesData = [
  {
    "SMS": 0,
    "IOS": 0,
    "ANDROID": 0,
    "EMAIL": 0,
    "currencyId": 11,
    "currencyCode": "CFA",
    "TELEGRAM": 0,
    "INBOX": 0
  },
  {
    "SMS": 10,
    "IOS": 10,
    "ANDROID": 10,
    "EMAIL": 10,
    "currencyId": 12,
    "currencyCode": "IND",
    "TELEGRAM": 10,
    "INBOX": 10
  }
]

const arr = chargesData.map(e => {
  const {currencyCode, currencyId, ...channels} = e;
  return {
    channels: channels,
    currency: {currencyCode, currencyId}
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what does `const {currencyCode, currencyId, ...channels} = e;` this line mean? what is `e`

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria you are welcome. ``e`` stands for the object in each iteration, and the destructuring assignment splits it into ``currencyCode``, ``currencyId``, and a ``channels`` object containing the rest of the attributes. I updated the answer with links to the docs for more details.